# ¿ Problema al poner el método onClick dentro de Fragment?

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente Fragment:

```
public class FragmentFirst extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FragmentFirst() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_second, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }




    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public void ActivityMatematicas3 (View v){

        final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(FragmentFirst.this.getActivity(), R.anim.anim1);
        v.startAnimation(animation);

        Intent siguiente = new Intent(FragmentFirst.this.getActivity(),Matematicas3.class);
        startActivity(siguiente);
    }
}
```

El problema es que no me detecta `ActivityMatematicas3` que está puesto en el metodo `onClick` en su respectivo .xml, no lo encuentra, y no sé por qué, entonces cuando hago click no funciona.

Mi xml el cual está referenciado `ActivityMatematicas3`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.teleco.espada.teleco.FragmentFirst"
    android:background="#EAE8F6" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button3"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/integral"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:onClick="ActivityMatematicas3"
            android:text="MATEMÁTICAS I"
            android:typeface="serif" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/phi"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:text="FÍSICA I"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button3"
            android:onClick="ActivityFisicaI" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/circuit"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:text="T.CIRCUITOS"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button3"
            android:onClick="ActivityTeoria"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/laptop"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:text="FCO"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:onClick="ActivityFco"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button3"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/phi"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:text="PROGRAMACIÓN"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:onClick="ActivityProgramacion"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button3" />

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: cómo? No... el fallo es en "ActivityMatematicas3" que es así como se llama el .java, no falla en el Intent.

Comment: porque mejor no usas OnClickListener?

Comment: @RfMvs ve mi respuesta, la opción 4 es primero asegurar que no existe un error en el método que no permite realizar el intent. Lo común en este caso es que el layout que carga el Fragment/Activity no contiene el boton que ejecuta el método.

Comment: @RfMvs Es importante también revises el LogCat para ver si existe algún mensaje de error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No debería fallar, te sugiero 4 detalles a revisar:

**1)** Asegurar que el layout que carga tu fragment contenga en verdad `android:onClick="[tu método a ejecutar]"`

En ocasiones he notado que no ejecuta el método simplemente porque no se encuentra en el layout que carga la clase.

**2)** Asegurar que en el `fragment` exista el método definido en `android:onClick` y que reciba un `View` como parámetro:

```
public void myMetodoClick(View v){
...
...
...
}
```

**3)** revisa que este bien definido tu método:

```
public void ActivityMatematicas3 (View v){
...
...
```

si notas tiene un espacio!, debería ser:

```
public void ActivityMatematicas3(View v){
...
...
```

**4)** Si tienes definido en el layout que carga el `Fragment` correctamente el boton y la ejecución del método, asegura el método a ejecutar no tiene algún error. Pudiera ser que se tiene un error el cual no permite se realice el Intent para abrir la `Activity` Matematicas3:

```
  public void ActivityMatematicas3 (View v){

        final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(FragmentFirst.this.getActivity(), R.anim.anim1);
        v.startAnimation(animation);

        Intent siguiente = new Intent(FragmentFirst.this.getActivity(),Matematicas3.class);
        startActivity(siguiente);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener en cuenta que al Fragmento le estás asignando en el `OncreateView` un XML diferente, así que cuando le des clic a ese botón, saldrá que es `Null`, porque no lo estás inflando realmente.

Lo que puedes hacer es inflar esa vista antes de usar ese elemento.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ActivityMatematicas3, null);
```

Después de inflar la vista, llamarías el elemento como lo harías normalmente

```
Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.tu_boton);
```

Y luego le podrías poner el `btn.setOnClickListener(this o new OnClick...etc)`.